# Insert space as a given amount in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable number (for example `3`) and two strings. How I can put `3` spaces between two string? output better to be alert like

```
var number=3;var string1="hello";var string2="world";alert(string1+"   "+string 2);
```

note that number must get with prompt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of `Array` constructor and `prompt`

```
var num = Number(prompt("Enter the number")); // fails if not number
alert(string1 + (Array(num + 1).join(" ")) + string2);
```

What `Array(num + 1).join(" ")` does is, it creates an array of length of the 
number inputted by the user + 1 and joins it by  `" "` using `Array.join`

Also you can do the below as per @FabrizioCalderan. Thanks mate!

```
alert([string1, string2].join(Array(num + 1).join(' ')));
```

Comment: or also `[string1, string2].join(Array(num + 1).join(' '));`